# Manually triggering wiselinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pjax

We are considering switching from PJAX to Wiselinks but haven't found documentation that allows us to do the following which was easy in PJAX:

```
if($.support.pjax) {
    $.pjax({url: new_url, container: '[data-pjax-container]'}); 
} else {
    window.location.href = new_url;
}
```

Is it possible to do the equivalent in Wiselinks?

EDIT

Actually the source code was pretty clear. This seems to work:

```
window.wiselinks.page.load(new_url);
```